# Как получить только значение столбцов в переменную из SQL запроса?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

Как получить только значения столбцов как результат SQL запроса?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
myvariable=$(mysql -u root -pPass <<EOF
use test
SELECT test_iduser FROM newbd;
EOF
)
echo ${myvariable}
```

Выводится и название самого столбца и значения, а хотелось бы получить только значения.

Comment: `| tail -n 1` .

Comment: Насколько я понимаю tail это команда для обработки текстовых файлов, а не работа с самим текстом в перемнной.

Comment: понял. исправляюсь: `переменная=$(программа | tail -n 1)`

Comment: Попробовал ваше предложение, не помогло.

Comment: А почему не помогло? Ничего не изменилось?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$ mysql --help
  -N, --skip-column-names
                      Don't write column names in results.
  -s, --silent        Be more silent. Print results with a tab as separator,
                      each row on new line.

$ ret=$(mysql -sN -u root -p<pass> <<EOF
use mysql
select User from user;
exit
EOF
)
$ echo "$ret"
test
root
```

Тот же результат в одну строку без *here-document*:

```
$ ret=$(mysql -sN -u root -p<pass> -D mysql -e "select user from user")
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!

Comment: Рад был помочь!